# loading external file using jquery and then making reference to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a js file that loads some content (external html file) into the DOM and then alerts the content that was just loaded

boo.html

```
<div id="tyler">
   Tyler
</div>
```

play.js

```
$('#result').load('../html/boo.html');
var mike = $('#tyler').text();
alert(mike);
```

file.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>A</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="play.js">
    </body>
</html>
```

For some strange reason when I `alert(mike)` What I get is blank. Cant you append a div with some id and then later reference the new div that you just injected?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.load()` is asynchronous. It goes off and does its thing and your code keeps executing in-line. So if you check for the content immediately, it won't be there yet. It takes a while for the server to respond, send you the HTML and insert it into the DOM.

You need to use a callback to do this. A callback is an event fired when an asynchronous event is complete.

```
$('#result').load('../html/boo.html',function() { alert("moo, this is the callback") });
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: forgot the closing parenthesis on `function( { alert...` should be `function() { alert...`